My Facebook App was approved of using page_messaging permission, but my chatbot still doesn't reply to public user
My App summary : Chatbot which can reply to end user automatically via Facebook messenger app.
Permission requested: page_messaging(Approved)
I had created the chatbot for facebook messsenger app and already submitted for app review process(page_messaging permission). After my app was approved I switched my app to LIVE mode and test my bot with an account that has no role in the app, so I found that the bot doesn't reply and webhook didn't trigger anything to my backend.
Do I have to request any additional permission or I need to setup anything else?
Thank you in advance
Exptected Result
A public user(no role in the facebook app) can chat with my chatbot normally like a test user(has role in the app).

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/, the 'pages_messaging' permission requires the 'pages_manage_metadata' and 'pages_show_list' permissions. Therefore, you will also need to request advanced permissions for 'pages_manage_metadata' and 'pages_show_list' to ensure the webhook functions for real users.
